# Invocation of Python's descriptor protocol from super

Tags: python, super, descriptor

In the Python [Descriptor HowTo guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), it is written that:

> A dotted lookup such as `super(A, obj).m` searches `obj.__class__.__mro__`
> for the base class `B` immediately following `A` and then returns
> `B.__dict__['m'].__get__(obj, A)`. If not a descriptor, `m` is returned
> unchanged.

This seems to suggest that the search for attribute `m` only happens in the `__dict__` of class `B`, which is the base class immediately following `A`, however, I think it should happen in all of the base classes in the mro following A. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

The lookup is basically the usual algorithm, but with a couple of beginning steps skipped:

1. <strike>Look for `m` in `obj.__dict__`.</strike>
2. <strike>Look for `m` in `type(m).__dict__`.</strike>
3. Look for `m` in a class in the MRO of `type(m)`, starting with the class *after* `A`.

Once `m` is found, *then* Python checks if `m` is a descriptor. If it is, `m.__get__` is called and its return value is the result. Otherwise, `m` itself is the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the description in the how to guide is not accurate then.

Comment: No, just awkwardly worded. It starts with the assumption that `B.__dict__['m']` *is* a descriptor (which, since `super` is usually used to access methods, will usually be true).